# Mongo/Mongoose field value aren't updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with my MongoDB collection. If i try to replace field in my item it won't get saved. It logs new value correctly, but nothing in DB really changes. What's wrong here?

```
exports.update = function (req, res) {
    const { entryid, userid } = req.params;
    let field;
    ['stop', 'description'].forEach(item => req.query[item] ? field = item : -1);

    db.TimeEntry.findById(entryid).then(function (entry) {
        (req.query[field] === undefined) ? entry[field] = 'no value specified' : entry[field] = req.query[field];
        console.log('v:', entry[field]);

        entry.save(function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            db.TimeEntry.find({ userId: userid })
                .then(foundEntries => res.status(200).json(foundEntries));
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TimeEntrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    start: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
        default: Date.now,
        required: true
    },
    stop: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    description: String,
    project: String,
    billable: Boolean,
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true })

TimeEntrySchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
    User.findById(this.userId).then(user => {
        user.entries.remove(this.id);
        user.save().then(function (e) {
            next();
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
});

const TimeEntry = mongoose.model('TimeEntry', TimeEntrySchema);
module.exports = TimeEntry;
```

Edit: Modified this way, still no effect.

```
` entry[field] = (!req.query[field]) ? 'TESTINGTESTING' : req.query[field];
        entry.markModified('description');

        console.log('v:', entry[field]);

        entry.save().then(function (err) {`
```

Final edit: Ok so this is the final solution.

```
exports.update = function (req, res) {
    const { entryid, userid } = req.params;
    let field;
    ['stop', 'description'].forEach(item => req.query[item] ? field = item : -1);

    db.TimeEntry.update({ _id: entryid }, {
        $set: {
            description: req.query[field] || 'no value specified'
        }
    }).then(function () {
        db.TimeEntry.find({ userId: userid })
            .then((foundEntries) => res.status(200).json(foundEntries))
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Try `entry.markModified(field); entry.save(...)`

Comment: added modified code to question edit. Nothing changed.

Comment: Replace this line `(req.query[field] === undefined) ? entry[field] = 'no value specified' : entry[field] = req.query[field]` with this : `entry[field] = req.query[field] || 'no value specified'`. It probably won't solve your current issue, but it's much less messy.

Comment: Check your Mongoose schema. If the 'description' field is not in it, then Mongoose will simply ignore it and not save it to the DB. For that matter, what is your schema? And what is `db` ?

Comment: Added schema to main question. db returns my two models.

Comment: doesn't it update the database correctly or does the `res.status(200).json(foundEntries)` return the wrong / not updated result?

Comment: json is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.update`:

```
return db.TimeEntry.update({ _id: entryid }, {
    $set: {
        [field]: req.query[field] || 'no value specified'
    }
  }
}).then(() => db.TimeEntry.find({ _id: entryid }))
  .then((resultEntries) => res.status(200).json(foundEntries))
```

Comment: Post the contents of your db table.

Comment: ok, after more experiments I found Your solution is working correctly. I will post final code in my  main post. Thanks ;]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:  `entry.save().exec(callbackFN);`
instead of `entry.save(callbackFN);` ?

Comment: No, this is not working (exec is not a function error). I have tried save().then(cb) instead but still no effect.

Comment: @Richard `entry.save().exec` --> Not a function. This is invalid.